# Dynamic Sheets(Array())

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to select a array of sheets using the Sheets(Array()) method.
The sheets I want to select are named in the cells of my workheet Printlist.
The sheetnames are listed form column D to K.

Not all cells are filled so if I use the folowing function it errors on the rows with blank cells. How can I avoid this error:

This is what the sheet looks like: 
[image]

And this is the code

```
Sub PDF_maken()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Mypath As String
    Dim strarray As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printlijst")
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each r In ws.Range("B20:B20").Cells

        If Not IsEmpty("B" & r.Row) Then

            Mypath = ws.Range("B" & r.Row).Text
            colCheck = 4

            Do Until Cells(r.Row, colCheck) = ""
               strarray = strarray & IIf(colCheck > 4, ",") & """" & Cells(r.Row, colCheck).Value & """"
                colCheck = colCheck + 1
            Loop

            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).Select
            ActiveWorkbook.SelectedSheets.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=Mypath & ws.Range("C" & r.Row).Text & ".pdf", _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular array rather than the `Array()` function to create the array. Then you can loop through the cells that contains sheet names and only add them if they're not blank.  Here's an example.

```
Sub PDF_maken()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim rMap As Range
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim aSheets() As String
    Dim lShCnt As Long
    Dim rSh As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printlist")
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rMap In ws.Range("B2:B" & lLastRow).Cells
        'Make sure there's a path
        If Not IsEmpty(rMap.Value) Then
            sPath = ws.Range("B" & rMap.Row).Text
            're-dimension an array to hold all the sheet names
            ReDim aSheets(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rMap.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 8)))
            'reset the counter
            lShCnt = 0
            'loop through all the cells that might have a sheet name
            'and add them to the array
            For Each rSh In rMap.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 8).Cells
                If Not IsEmpty(rSh.Value) Then
                    lShCnt = lShCnt + 1
                    aSheets(lShCnt) = rSh.Text
                End If
            Next rSh
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(aSheets).Select
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, sPath & rMap.Offset(0, 1).Text & ".pdf"
        End If
    Next rMap

    ws.Select

End Sub
```

If you get `Error 9: Subscript Out of Range` there are three things to check:

1. The first one is that you spelled a sheet name wrong. Make sure there are no spaces or other funny business that makes it look like you have a good sheet name and you don't.
2. Next, make sure you qualify all of your references back to the workbook level. Depending on where your code is, unqualified references can point to different places. Don't ever use `Sheets()`. Always use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets()` or some other workbook reference. That will make sure you're not trying to access a sheet in a workbook that you didn't intend to.
3. Finally, you can get that error if you pass numbers to Sheets because your sheet names are numbers. Or rather they look like numbers, but they're really text.  `sheets(array(1234,4567)).select` is different than `sheets(array("1234","4567")).select`. You have to pass strings to Sheets or you'll get that error.  Kind of. You *can* pass numbers, but it will Select the sheets based on their index numbers rather than their names. That's why you have to be extra careful when your sheet names look like numbers.

Comment: I tried both methods but the macro freezes on the line ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strarray).Select

Comment: I got the following error Error 9 Subscript out range. When there is just one sheet in the array it works but when there ar more in it I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Do a similar loop,

something like

`colCheck=4
do until cells(r.row,colCheck)=""
    strArray=strarray & iif(colCheck>4,",","") & cells(r.row,colCheck).value
    colCheck=colCheck+1
loop`

then you'll get something like a,b,c   I've not tested this, so may need some tweaking.  I'll revisit in a moment.

Comment: It works to a certain point, I used Dim strarray As String and added your code. Now I get an error in the botton code at the following line    ws.Sheets(Array(strarray)).Select

Comment: add the sheets to an array, rather than composing a string to do the same.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the array object in help, what you are trying to replicate, then google array's in VBA and you'll find out how to add to them.  You need to do some yourself :)